# Strapi returns Invalid Token using Google provider

Tags: strapi

For local account, strapi validates the local jwt successfully. However, when I sign in using Google provider, /connect/google/callback redirects to the homepage with access_token, raw[access_token], raw[id_token], etc... I have tried all of these tokens, and strapi returns all of them invalid.

Also, I don't see the account that I signed in with google in Users(content-type).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of Strapi's team member. I have coded a small example that fully explains how to setup Strapi  to enable Google as a provider.

Here is the documentation and the associated [documentation](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/login-react).

What you need to do when Google redirects your user to your app is to send another request with the code contained in the URL see the [example](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/login-react/react-login-front-end-app/app/containers/ConnectPage).

Comment: can you please explain little bit more? React is not my forte. After it redirects to the homepage, what query param from the url do I use? what page do I make a get request to get jwt from strapi?
React is not my forte, so I tried to trace the code. I understand the AuthPage container which has the login form and redirects user to Google,etc... but the ConnectPage, it seems that where I make Get to /connect/:provider/:id? -- I'm confused about this id...

Comment: Well the ConnectPage container is just used to send a request to the API to retrieve your user token. I made a dedicated route for this step so it is easier to understand the logic. Here is a link to an article which explains the authentication flow with a custom provider such as Google : https://medium.com/strapi/protected-routes-and-authentication-with-react-and-node-js-d31d234644cd.

Comment: thanks @soupette! After the it redirected with a query of access_token,  I made a request to connect/google/callback${query} per the example. It came back with an error 
"error=Grant: missing session or misconfigured provider". I looked it up with grantjs, it seems either the cookie wasn't set. 
Can please you run a quick check on your example to see if version alpha10.2 still working correctly?

Comment: I tried and I got the same error can you post an issue on github? Thanks a lot so we can fix it soon